# Gatlin DSL randomSwitch sharing data across the Choices

Tags: gatling

I am running the soak tests using RandomSwitch to test in distribution:

```
ScenarioBuilder getScenario2(){
        return scenario("Scenario").exec(getAuthenticationChain())
                .randomSwitch().on(
                        new Choice.WithWeight(58.00636267, exec(getCreateProductASyncChain(10, "S1"))),
                        new Choice.WithWeight(7.246376812, exec(getCreateProductAsyncChain(30, "S2"))),
                        new Choice.WithWeight(3.817603393, exec(getCreateProductAsyncChain(50, "S3"))),
                        new Choice.WithWeight(4.91339696, exec(getCreateProductAsyncChain(70, "S4"))),
                        new Choice.WithWeight(2.47437257, exec(getCreateProductAsyncChain(90, "S5"))),
                        new Choice.WithWeight(2.721809827, exec(getCreateProductAsyncChain(110, "S6")),
                        new Choice.WithWeight(1.590668081, exec(getCreateProductAsyncChain(130, "S7")),
                        new Choice.WithWeight(19.22940969, exec(getCreateProductAsyncChain(150, "S8"))
                        );
    }
```

*getCreateProductASyncChain* method is preparing the chain for run:

```
ChainBuilder getCreateProductASyncChain(int productCount, String name){
        String createProducString = getCreateProductRequestString(productCount, "SYNC");
        return exec(
                http("CreateProducts")
                        .post(graphQlUrl)
                        .header("Authorization", " #{Authorization}")
                        .header("cookie", "#{cookie}")
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .body(StringBody(createProducString))
                        .check(status().is(200))
                        .check(bodyString().saveAs("responseBody"))
                        .check(jsonPath("$['data']['content']['content_obj']['status']").in( "success", "error"))
                        .check(jsonPath("$['data']['content']['content_obj']['status']").saveAs("status"))
                        .check(jsonPath("$['data']['content']['content_obj']['id']").saveAs("id")))
        
                .exec(session -> {
                    System.out.println("Response Body:****************************"+session.getString("responseBody"));
                    
                    return session;
                });
    }
```

I am creating productCount no of product json objects, every product request json has name as one of the field, I am generating name with randomUUID in *getCreateProductRequestString* method:

```
for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
            productSb.append("{\"name\": \"Test_prd "+java.util.UUID.randomUUID()+"}")
            
        }
```

API will throw validation errors if product name is
duplicate.

What I have observed in API logs is that the product name is getting duplicated when I run the scenario for 1 hour but same works fine if I run it for 15 mins or less.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Everything that's not wrapped in a function is only executed once when the simulation is built. You should do:

```java
.body(StringBody(session -> getCreateProductRequestString(productCount, "SYNC")))
```